# proc sql: full joins with multiple matches, only keep one

Tags: sql, sas

I'm merging two datasets in SAS using `full join`, and there are occasions where there are more than one matches. For example, I have the two datasets where `Pat` is the patient ID, `ID` is the form ID and `Date` is the intervention date. Dataset 1 is a high level form and dataset 2 is a more detailed, and need merging based on `Pat` and `Date`. Some patients have more than one intervention per day:

```
data have1;
    input Pat ID1 Date1 :ddmmyy10.;
    format Date1 ddmmyy10.;
    datalines;
    1001 1 06/09/2023
    1001 2 06/09/2023
    ;
run;

data have2;
    input Pat ID2 Date2 :ddmmyy10.;
    format Date2 ddmmyy10.;
    datalines;
    1001 3 06/09/2023
    1001 4 06/09/2023
    ;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
    select *
    from have1
    full join have2
    on have1.Pat eq have2.Pat
    and have1.Date1 eq have2.Date2;
quit;
```

This gives me a dataset with four rows, with each combination of possible outputs. Is there a way that I can match only one, so I end up with two unique combinations as opposed to the four possible combinations?

Comment: Dor the values of `ID1` and `ID2` or the number of visits in `have1` and `have2` interest you?

Comment: The ID1 and ID2 are important, as its used to identify the full form later on.  The number of visits will match between the datasets, but may be more than one per day.

Comment: The key here is to number the rows per Pat and Date in the tables, so you can include the row number in the join. In SQL this is usually done with `ROW_NUMBER`. I don't know whether SAS features this, though.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "the full form".

Answer (score 0):

**If `ID1` and `ID2` are irrelevant for you and you are an `SQL` addict:**

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select DISTINCT coalesce(have1.Pat, have2.Pat) as Pat, 
                    have1.Date1, have2.Date2
    from have1
    full join have2
    on have1.Pat eq have2.Pat
    and have1.Date1 eq have2.Date2;
quit;
```

**If `ID1` and `ID2` do matter, you can still get useful results with `proc sql`, for instance**

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select coalesce(have1.Pat, have2.Pat) as Pat, 
           coalesce(have1.Date1, have2.Date2) as Date  format=ddmmyy10., 
           min(ID1) as first_ID1,  
           max(ID1) as last_ID1, 
           count(distinct ID1) as no_ID1, 
           min(ID2) as first_ID2,  
           max(ID2) as last_ID2, 
           count(distinct ID2) as no_ID2
    from have1
    full join have2
    on have1.Pat eq have2.Pat
    and have1.Date1 eq have2.Date2
    group by 1, 2;
quit;
```

Testing with

```
data have1;
    input Pat ID1 Date1 :ddmmyy10.;
    format Date1 ddmmyy10.;
    datalines;
1001 0 06/09/2023
1001 1 06/09/2023
1001 2 06/09/2023
1001 3 07/09/2023
1001 4 07/09/2023
1001 5 08/09/2023
run;

data have2;
    input Pat ID2 Date2 :ddmmyy10.;
    format Date2 ddmmyy10.;
    datalines;
1001 6 06/09/2023
1001 7 06/09/2023
1001 8 08/09/2023
1001 9 08/09/2023
run;
```

| Pat | Date | first_ID1 | last_ID1 | no_ID1 | first_ID2 | last_ID2 | no_ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 06/09/2023 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 7 | 2 |
| 1001 | 07/09/2023 | 3 | 4 | 2 | . | . | 0 |
| 1001 | 08/09/2023 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 8 | 9 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using SQL?  That just makes things harder as SQL has no concept of the order of observations.  You will need to use the same names for the BY variables, but you can use dataset options to change the names.

```
data have1;
    input Pat ID1 Date1 :ddmmyy10.;
    format Date1 yymmdd10.;
datalines;
1001 1 06/09/2023
1001 2 06/09/2023
;

data have2;
    input Pat ID2 Date2 :ddmmyy10.;
    format Date2 yymmdd10.;
datalines;
1001 3 06/09/2023
1001 4 06/09/2023
;

data want;
  merge have1(in=in1 rename=(date1=date))
        have2(in=in2 rename=(date2=date))
  ;
  by pat date;
  if first.date;
run;
```

Result

```
OBS     Pat    ID1          date    ID2

 1     1001     1     2023-09-06     3
```

PS Don't indent in-line data, it will just cause you confusion.  Don't indent the DATALINES statement to remind the editor you don't want the data lines indented either.  Also don't display dates in either DMY or MDY order as either one will confuse half of your audience.

Answer (score 0):

**A solution that preserves every detail is**

```
proc transpose prefix=ID1_
    data=have1 
    out=trans1(rename=(date1=date));
    by Pat Date1;
    var ID1;
run;

proc transpose prefix=ID2_ 
    data=have2 
    out=trans2(rename=(date2=date));
    by Pat Date2;
    var ID2;
run;

data want;
  merge trans1 trans2 ;
  by pat date;
run;
```

Testing with

```
data have1;
    input Pat ID1 Date1 :ddmmyy10.;
    format Date1 ddmmyy10.;
    datalines;
1001 0 06/09/2023
1001 1 06/09/2023
1001 2 06/09/2023
1001 3 07/09/2023
1001 4 07/09/2023
1001 5 08/09/2023
run;

data have2;
    input Pat ID2 Date2 :ddmmyy10.;
    format Date2 ddmmyy10.;
    datalines;
1001 6 06/09/2023
1001 7 06/09/2023
1001 8 08/09/2023
1001 9 08/09/2023
run;
```

you clearly see the outer join behaviour

| Pat | date | *NAME* | ID1_1 | ID1_2 | ID1_3 | ID2_1 | ID2_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 06/09/2023 | ID2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 7 |
| 1001 | 07/09/2023 | ID1 | 3 | 4 | . | . | . |
| 1001 | 08/09/2023 | ID2 | 5 | . | . | 8 | 9 |